# Finding a value for a variable according to different elevations

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have a DEM raster file of a specific region

```
DEMRASTER

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 47, 89, 4183  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 60.75, 105.25, 15.75, 39.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : newlowelevation1 
values     : 1, 6136.012  (min, max)
```

I have another raster file of variable "GPP":

```
GPPRASTER
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 47, 89, 4183  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 60.75, 105.25, 15.75, 39.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -0.333333, 0  (min, max)
```

How can I find the values of the GPP raster according to elevation? For instance, if I want to find a mean value of GPP for elevation from 0-2000m or 5500 to 6136m? What will be the basic code for this?

I have tried removing pixels based on the elevation that I did not want from the DEM raster file, but it is a method that takes too long. I am sure that there is a code for this, but can't put my hand on it as I am a new beginner at R myself. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal self-contained, reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
elev <- raster(ncol=47, nrow=89, ext=extent(60.75, 105.25, 15.75, 39.25))
elev <- init(elev, "cell")
gdp <- flip(elev, "y")/100
```

Solution:

```
ezones <- cut(elev, c(0,1000,2000,Inf))
zonal(gdp, ezones)
#     zone     mean
#[1,]    1 36.83058
#[2,]    2 26.83396
#[3,]    3 10.92250
```

Or with `terra`:

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.2.1
ev <- rast(ncol=47, nrow=89, ext=ext(60.75, 105.25, 15.75, 39.25))
ev <- init(ev, "cell")
gd <- flip(ev, "vertical")/100
names(gd) <- "gdp"
names(ev) <- "elevation"
```

Solution:

```
ez <- classify(ev, c(0,1000,2000,Inf))
zonal(gd, ez)
#    elevation      gdp
#1    0 - 1000 36.83580
#2 1000 - 2000 26.84370
#3  2000 - inf 10.92752
```

Comment: Can you shed light on what is gdp <- flip(elev, "y")/100?

Comment: I am just creating example data such that you get higher gdp at lower elevations. It does not really matter for the question at hand..